# postgresql error: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect in django

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, django-postgresql

when i migrate in django
the django have return error below

```
$ python manager.py migrate
```

> django.db.utils.InternalError: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.3.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect

i researched many posts but not found any solution.
Does anyone know the solution?
my system info is below

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>   Release:    16.04
>   Codename:   xenial

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

> ii  postgresql-9.6                     9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1                        amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.6 server
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-pgrouting           2.3.2+ds-2.pgdg16.04+1                     amd64        Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-pgrouting-scripts   2.3.2+ds-2.pgdg16.04+1                     all          Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS - scripts
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3         2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.6
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3-scripts 2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.6 -- scripts
>   ii  postgresql-client-9.6              9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1                        amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.6
>   ii  postgresql-client-common           180.pgdg16.04+1                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
>   ii  postgresql-common                  180.pgdg16.04+1                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
>   ii  postgresql-contrib                 9.6+180.pgdg16.04+1                        all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
>   ii  postgresql-contrib-9.6             9.6.2-1.pgdg16.04+1                        amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

> ii  postgis                            2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL
>   ii  postgis-doc                        2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- documentation
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3         2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.6
>   ii  postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3-scripts 2.3.2+dfsg-1~exp2.pgdg16.04+1              all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.6 -- scripts

Comment: It is obvious that the `liblwgeom` you have installed is not the correct one for the PostGIS version, but I don't know enough about Ubuntu packaging to help you any further.

Comment: thanks you for answer, i will search correct liblwgeom version!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that you're using an older version of GEOS(I'm guessing 3.4. You can find out the version by running geos-config --version). What you need to do is uninstall the current version of GEOS and reinstall a newer version:

Delete the geos files from /usr/bin /usr/local/bin usr/lib usr/local/lib. Should be fairly easy to identify

Run the following to install version 3.5:

```
$ wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.5.1.tar.bz2

$ tar xjf geos-3.5.1.tar.bz2

$ cd geos-3.5.2

$ ./configure

$ make

$ sudo make install

$ sudo ldconfig
```

Edit: Use the most relevant version of GEOS for your project. It's not mandatory to use 3.5